# Difference between instantiating a class object with Constructor parameter and * operator without parameters C++

Tags: c++, constructor, polymorphism, default-constructor

I came across this tutorial link when studying OOPS concepts in C++. http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_polymorphism.htm

In the base class `Shape`, it has constructor with two parameters to set its protected variables and in `main()` I thought the only way to create an object for class `Shape` is by doing something like `Shape shape(2,4)` to match the constructor in `Shape` class.

Can someone say how the instantiation `Shape *shape` without any parameters work and whats the difference between creating object by `Shape shape(2,4)` and `Shape *shape`.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Shape{
protected:
    int w,h;

public:

    Shape(int a, int b){
        w=a;
        h=b;
    }
    int area(){
        cout << "Shape class area" << endl;
        return 0;
    }
};

class Rect:public Shape{

public:

    Rect(int a, int b):Shape(a,b) {}
    int area(){
        cout <<"Rect class area " << endl;
        return w*h;
    }
};

class Tri:public Shape{

public:

    Tri(int a, int b):Shape(a,b) {}
    int area(){
        cout << "Tri class area" << endl;
        return (w*h)/2;
    }
};

int main(){

    Shape *shape;
    Rect r(4,5);
    Tri t(4,5);
    shape=&r;
    shape->area();
    shape=&t;
    shape->area();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Rather than relying on people reading a linked article, which might not be there when somebody finds this question in several years' time, please post relevant samples of code as part of your question so that we can understand it by itself. Stack Overflow is not just for the answers you need now but the same question somebody else has in the future.

Comment: Apologize. Added the code in the initial question above. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Statement

```
Shape *shape;
```

does not create any instance of the class Shape.
It declares a variable that is a pointer of type `Shape *` and that is not initialized that is it has indetermined value provided that the declaration declares a local variable.

As for the constructor then the only constructor of the class with two parameters is also the default constructor of the class because each parameter has a default argument.

```
Shape( int a=0, int b=0)
           ^^^      ^^^  
{
   //...
}
```

Thus you can write for example

```
Shape sh;
```

and data members of the created object will be initialized by these default arguments.
This declaration is equivalent to

```
Shape sh( 0, 0 );
```

Comment: Thanks! I quickly added the code in the above program.

Shape sh;
sh.area() // This gave me an error saying there is no matching constructor

whereas when I wrote 

Shape sh(0,0);
sh.area() // it is able to access the method properly
Have I misunderstood your answer. Please clarify. Thanks!!

Comment: @Gangadhar The code does not correspond to the code shown at the reference because the constructor of the class Shape now is not the default constructor. It does not have the default arguments for both its parameters.

Comment: Thank you very much for the clarification. I see the difference you mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

```
Shape *shape;
```

This does not create a Shape object. It creates an uninitialized Shape pointer, which can be used for storing the address of a Shape object (or an object of a class which is derived from Shape). You can see it used in the page you linked to:

```
// store the address of Rectangle
shape = &rec;
// call rectangle area.
shape->area();
```

Comment: So this means. if we want an object for Shape class it should be instantiated separately and the same *shape cannot be re-used?

Comment: @Gangadhar: I don't understand your comment.

Comment: So if my class Shape has another method say 
void print(){ cout << "Print something"; }
Can I do something like shape.print() or do I need a different object instantiated for Shape class?

Comment: @Gangadhar: You can do `shape->print();` as long as `shape` points to (*i.o.w. holds the address of*) a valid Shape or Shape derived object. In the case of the example, it would be equivalent to either `rec.print();` or `tri.print();`, depending upon which object's address it held at the time.

Comment: Ya I get it now. Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Declaring a `Shape*` is not an operator, it's a different type. The type is pointer to shape. This differs from a directly declaring a shape in many ways:

- It's not a shape, but a variable that points to a shape.
- When using inheritance, we can use a pointer to base class (`Shape*`) to point to a child class (`Rectangle`).
- Note that I didn't put `*` after `Rectangle`. That's because a pointer point to an instance of a class, not to another pointer, except when you have pointer to pointer.
- When declaring a `Shape*`, the constructor is not called, as your pointer will point an existing instance or a new instance, using the `new` operator, or to no instance.
- A pointer that points to nothing is usually called a null pointer.
- You should read about pointers and references before polymorphism.

A pointer declared without parameter has an undefined value. If you want a null pointer, you should declaring it like this:

```
Shape* ptrToShape = nullptr;
```

Comment: Thank you very much